# How to Html Table structure

Tags: html, html-table

I'm have a pretty complex table to be created. I'm not sure how to proceed. I have created a simple one but need suggestion on how to proceed.

Required Table Structure
[image]

Current Table Structure

[image]

```
<table class="ccTbl" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Group</th>
            <th class="tblServHdr">
                <span>Type1</span>
            </th>
            <th class="tblServHdr">
                <span>Type2</span>
            </th>
            <th class="tblServHdr">
                <span>Type3</span>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Group-A</td>
            <td>$0.0</td>
            <td>$0.0</td>
            <td>$0.0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Group-B</td>
            <td>$0.0</td>
            <td>$0.0</td>
            <td>$0.0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Group-C</td>
            <td>$0.0</td>
            <td>$0.0</td>
            <td>$0.0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Total</td>
            <td>$0.0</td>
            <td>$0.0</td>
            <td>$0.0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <input type="button" value="Save"></input>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="button" value="Create "></input>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="button" value="Delete"></input>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>        
</table>
```

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/6qJeP/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [rowspan](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_rowspan.asp) here.

Use this:

```
<table class="ccTbl" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th>Group</th>
                    <th class="tblServHdr">
                        <span>Type1</span>
                    </th>
                    <th class="tblServHdr">
                        <span>Type2</span>
                    </th>
                    <th class="tblServHdr">
                        <span>Type3</span>
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td rowspan=3>Group-A</td>
                    <td>$1.0</td>
                    <td>$0.0</td>
                    <td>$0.0</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>$2.0</td>
                    <td>$0.0</td>
                    <td>$0.0</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>$3.0</td>
                    <td>$0.0</td>
                    <td>$0.0</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td rowspan=2>Group-B</td>
                    <td>$1.0</td>
                    <td>$0.0</td>
                    <td>$0.0</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>$2.0</td>
                    <td>$0.0</td>
                    <td>$0.0</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Group-C</td>
                    <td>$0.0</td>
                    <td>$0.0</td>
                    <td>$0.0</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Total</td>
                    <td>$0.0</td>
                    <td>$0.0</td>
                    <td>$0.0</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="button" value="Save"></input>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="button" value="Create "></input>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="button" value="Delete"></input>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>

        </table>
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6qJeP/5/)

Comment: So if I add tr through js I need to update rowspan each time ?

Comment: Just an extra note: If you want to achieve the exact same effect that you have as your "Required Table Structure" you will need additional elements and formatting rules.  For example: to put the text at the top of the cell you can use `vertical-align: text-top;` and if you want those little trash cans to be clickable you'll need to put a div inside your cell with all those trash can images positioned properly or use one image with an image map.

Comment: @user it is another question. And it is not as hard, as you can assume. Create new one and somebody will help you with it. Not me, going work at the moment.